# Public or private?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Coursetro {

   string fName;
   uint age;

   function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
       fName = _fName;
       age = _age;
   }

   function getInstructor() private constant returns (string, uint) {
       return (fName, age);
   }

}
```

I read, that all in blockchain can be seen. I don't understand private in that case. I have an example of code. Does it mean that nobody can get or see data from getInstructor?

Answer (score 0):

Private and public in modifiers in solidity are used to declae the visibility of the function. That is who can call this function. That being said you have the following modifiers:

```
public - all
private - only this contract
internal - only this contract and contracts deriving from it
external - Cannot be accessed internally, only externally.
```

These modifeirs do not affect who can read the code and who cannot.